# Modify and return variable inline

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get the syntax for an inline function that can take in a parameter do a simple modification and return it all in one line.

Something like this:

```
(options) => { options.public = true; return options; }
```

Comment: That exact syntax will work just fine, in ES6 and TypeScript, so what's your question?

Comment: If you are looking for even shorter version - `inline_fn = ((options) => (options.public = true) && options)`

Comment: @kiddorails this seems to return the function itself when i want it to return a modified `options` object

Comment: It's a **function**. It totally depends on how you invoke it. On invocation, it shall return the modified object itself.

Comment: For instance `((options) => (options.public = true) && options)({ok: 'ok'})` will return `{ok: "ok", public: true}`.

Comment: Inline *with what?!* What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @kiddorails Your last comment is what I wanted. Submit it as the answer please.

Comment: In that case isn't your question just *"how do I call a function"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is pretty ambiguous. From discussion, I gather that *americanslon* wants a self-invoking function which accepts an object and return the modified object.

Original function:

```
(options) => { options.public = true; return options; }
```

Self invoking variant:

```
((options) => { options.public = true; return options; })({ok: 'ok'})
// {ok: 'ok', public: true}
```

[Read more about self invoking functions](https://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/)